# Change String to Float with (" ") in string

Tags: python

Ok, i have string like that in a file

> "0.9986130595207214","16.923500061035156","16.477115631103516","245.2451171875","107.35090637207031","118.8438720703125","254.64633178710938","255.2373046875","264.1331481933594","28.91413116455078"

and i have multiple row.

how to change the data to float or number, i have problem because the item become ' "0.9986130595207214" '.

this code that i've write :

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("data.csv",dtype=str,delimiter=',')
for y in data:
    for x in y:
        print(float(x))
```

and got error :

> print(float(x)) ValueError: could not convert string to float:
>   '"0.9986130595207214"'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, you got:

```
x = '"0.9986130595207214"'
```

Thus, you first need to get rid of the brackets.

```
float(x.strip('"'))
```

Output:

```
0.9986130595207214
```